# A bound for the zeros of an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f$ be analytic on $\bar{B}(0,R)$ with $|f(z)|≤M$ for $|z|≤R$ and $|f(0)| = a > 0$. Show that the number of zeros of $f$ in $B(0,\frac{1}{3}R)$ is less than or equal to $\frac{1}{\log2}\log(\frac{M}{a}).$

As a hint we can consider the function $$g(z)=f(z)\left[\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{z}{z_{k}}\right)\right]^{-1},$$ where $(z_{k})_{k=1}^{n}$ are the zeros of $f$ in $B(0,\frac{1}{3}R).$

My attempt is based in the following:

Observe that $|g(0)|=|f(0)|=a,$ then we can consider $\displaystyle\max_{|z|\leq R}{|g(z)|}\leq M|\left[\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{z}{z_{k}}\right)\right]^{-1}|$ but I have problems estimating a bound for the modulus of the product. I would like to prove that $|\left[\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{z}{z_{k}}\right)\right]^{-1}|\leq 2^{-n}$ to finish the proof but I'm stuck.

Other thought is using maximum modulus Theorem but I don't find a value in which $f$ maximizes in modulus.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that, if $|z|=M$, then
$$
\left|1-\frac{z}{z_k}\right|\ge \left|\frac{z}{z_k}\right|-1=\frac{M}{|z_k|}-1\ge \frac{M}{\frac M3}-1=2,
$$
since $|z_k|<\frac{M}{3}$.

Hence,

$$
\left|\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac{z}{z_k}\right)^{-1}\right|\le 2^{-n}.
$$

Comment: You probably mean $|z|=R$?

Comment: Why are we looking at $R/3$ and not $r \in (0,R)$ ?

Comment: @user1952009: $z_k$ are assumed to be the zeros in $B(0,R/3)$.

Comment: Thank you @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis. It was very useful.

Comment: Exactly @AlexR. Is $|z|=R.$

Comment: @AlexR. yes but is there a reason for choosing $r = R/3$ instead of $0 < r < R$ ?

Comment: @user1952009: If I understand your question correctly, then yes, the problem would generalize to any $0<r<R$.